# Weird behavior of Python iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I was playing around with Python generators and the `itertools` module and tried making an infinite version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Here is my code:

```
from itertools import count, ifilter, islice

def sieve_broken():
    candidates = count(start=2)
    while True:
        prime = next(candidates)
        yield prime
        candidates = ifilter(lambda n: n % prime, candidates)
```

When I test it out, I get this:

```
>>> print list(islice(sieve_broken(), 10))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

But if I replace the reassignment of `candidates` with a function like so:

```
def sieve_fixed():
    def exclude_multiples(factor, numbers):
        return ifilter(lambda n: n % factor, numbers)

    candidates = count(start=2)
    while True:
        prime = next(candidates)
        yield prime
        candidates = exclude_multiples(prime, candidates)
```

I get:

```
>>> print list(islice(sieve_fixed(), 10))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

I can't figure out why the first version doesn't work. As far as I can tell, the two versions should be equivalent. Does anyone know why they're not the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've fallen prey to [a very common pitfall when using closures in Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271-these-nasty-closures-caveats-for-the-closure-enthu/): closures carry their scope, and you keep replacing the value in the same scope.

```
candidates = ifilter(lambda n, prime=prime: n % prime, candidates)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... where am I defining a function that returns a function?

Comment: @user1475412: You aren't returning it, but there's one as the first argument to `ifilter()` regardless.